# Using facebook comments inside facebook app

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add a facebook comments box using the social plugin to an application which will be running inside facebook as a facebook app.

When I view the app via its url it works fine however when I view the app in the dev facebook app the comments plugin does not load. Does anyone know if this is possible or if there are any additional settings required.

I have tried setting the data-href to the url of where the app is served from and the url of the facebook app neither seem to work

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="[MYDOMAIN]” data-num-posts="30" data-width="470"></div>
```

The code is just the standard snippet from fb js sdk

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '[MYAPPID], // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    // Additional initialization code here
  };

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a channel file and channelUrl.

From the [Facebook JavaScript SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):
*"...pages that include code to communicate across frames may cause Social Plugins to show up as blank without a channelUrl..."*

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```